# How to specify a eclipselink converter for an element collection?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a class with an collection of strings representing IP addresses.

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "t_ips",
                 joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent"))
@Column(name = "c_ip")
private List<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the PostgreSQL table `t_ips`, the column `c_ip` is defined with type inet. I have a working EclipseLink converter for converting a string into an inet value, but I don't know who to specifiy the converter for this element collection. Simple adding the `@Convert` annotation to `ips` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Convert should work.  Ensure you defined the Convert with the same name.

How does it "not work" exactly?  What error do you get?

You can check the mapping at runtime or in a DescriptorCustomizer and check if the valueConverter was set on the DirectCollectionMapping.

Comment: If I put `@Convert` on `ips` EclipseLink is not able to create an entity manager. There is no usefull error message at all. It would be perfect so have a working example for my scenario.